# How come after first install can only boot in recovery with video=800x600 acpi=off nomodereset hp mini 1030 14 lts

Tags: boot, display, display-resolution

Having this problem with both Ubuntu 14 lts and Lulbuntu 14 lts. n270 processor.

note I had to use video=800x600-24@60 to install

Please help me so I can boot in in regular mode!

thanks!

Comment: anybody? please!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `sudo lshw`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide the link back into your question so we can see what exact hardware you have. Then leave a comment @Fabby.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the black bar at left and repeated top inch of window at bottom, it's hardware... keep your clamshell mostly closed (only an inch or two open to allow the screen wires and hinges to stay clear of each other.

Power down, close clamshell, open clamshell just an inch or two, power up. If it doesn't work give the closed laptop a few **GENTLE* knocks upside it's noggin on the side to make the wires giggle just a bit, then repeat power down and power up with clamshell open just a bit.